# \jobname in Gummi

Tags: conditionals, jobname, gummi

The command `\jobname` usually print the file name without the path and extension, so inside a file called `foo.tex` will print just `foo`. With `pdflatex foo.test` or compiling from LaTeXila certainly I obtained this result. But from [Gummi](http://dev.midnightcoding.org/projects/gummi) what I obtain is `.foo.tex`

Does anyone know why Gummi compiles differently and how I could get the usual `\jobname` behavior in Gummi?

**Edit:**
Based on helpful answers of @JosephWright and @Herbert
I wonder if it is possible to do the \jobname correction in Gummi only if the source have the .swp extensión or .tex persist in \jobname.

That is, I would like a solution like:

```
\makeatletter
\let\JobName\jobname
\ifthenelse{\equal{\detokenize{foo}}{\jobname}}
{}
{
\def\@JobName.#1.#2\@nil{#1}
\def\jobname{\expandafter\@JobName\JobName\@nil}
}
\makeatother
```

This conditional works to check if the jobname is foo or not, but I want a general solution, independent of the file name (not limited to the string foo).

Comment: How robust do you want 'auto-magic to be? For example, might there be multiple `.` in the file name? Do we need to cope with a hidden file which is not one created by Gummi?

Comment: @JosephWright, I alway use dots only to mark the extension, so for me is enough that jobname end with `.tex` or start with `.` or the source have the `.swp` extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking a look at the 'Build Log' I get with a `foo.tex` test file, it seems Gummi actually compiles `.foo.tex.swp`, which is hidden on Unix due to the leading `.`, and which has extension `.swp` not `.tex`. So TeX is showing you the correct information. For example, with demo file

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Hello world
\end{document}
```

saved as `foo.tex` I get log

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012)
 \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(/home/joseph/Desktop/.foo.tex.swp
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, dumylang, nohyphenation, ge
rman-x-2012-05-30, ngerman-x-2012-05-30, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ibycus, arabi
c, armenian, basque, bulgarian, catalan, pinyin, coptic, croatian, czech, danis
h, dutch, ukenglish, usenglishmax, esperanto, estonian, ethiopic, farsi, finnis
h, french, friulan, galician, german, ngerman, swissgerman, monogreek, greek, h
ungarian, icelandic, assamese, bengali, gujarati, hindi, kannada, malayalam, ma
rathi, oriya, panjabi, tamil, telugu, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, 
kurmanji, latin, latvian, lithuanian, mongolian, mongolianlmc, bokmal, nynorsk,
 polish, portuguese, romanian, romansh, russian, sanskrit, serbian, serbianc, s
lovak, slovenian, spanish, swedish, turkish, turkmen, ukrainian, uppersorbian, 
welsh, loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/tmp/.foo.tex.aux) [1{/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updma
p/pdftex.map}] (/tmp/.foo.tex.aux) )</usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/fonts/t
ype1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on /tmp/.foo.tex.pdf (1 page, 11541 bytes).
SyncTeX written on /tmp/.foo.tex.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on /tmp/.foo.tex.log.
```

I'm afraid I don't have a solution (other than 'use a different editor'), as there does not seem to be a Gummi setting to alter this behaviour.

---

The edited question asks for a 'flexible' approach based on Herbert's code. With the restriction that this assumes a simple case (the file name contains only a single `.` to separate the extension, except if it starts `.`where Gummi is in use):

```
\makeatletter
\begingroup
  \def\@jobname#1.#2\q@nil{%
    \ifx\relax#1\relax
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@@jobname
    \else
      \expandafter\@@@jobname
    \fi
      \jobname\q@nil
  }
  \def\@@jobname.#1.#2\q@nil{#1}
  \def\@@@jobname#1\q@nil{#1}
  \xdef\jobname{\expandafter\@jobname\jobname.\q@nil}
\endgroup
\makeatother
```

Comment: Works like a charm. I will accept this answer but thanks to @Herbert (upvoted too) . Certainly you're both TeX gurus.

Answer (score 3):

use in the preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\let\JobName\jobname
\def\@JobName.#1.#2\@nil{#1}
\def\jobname{\expandafter\@JobName\JobName\@nil}
\makeatother
```

then `\jobname` works as usual. The above is only useful for running a file with `gummi`.